# How to get correct color value for preset Google Calendar colors via API

Tags: google-calendar-api

According to the docs (ref [calendar](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendarList) and [color](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/colors)) the calendar colors can  be retrieved via the properties *"backgroundColor"*, *"foregroundColor"* and/or *"colorId"*.

In my original Google Calendar I have a calendar with color called 'cacao' and when I inspect the page the color of this calendar is **rgb(121, 85, 72) / #795548**. However when I retrieve the colors for that agenda through the API (either directly the backgroundColor value from the Calendar object or via looking up the colorId in the Colors object, they both match) the returned color is **rgb(202, 189, 191) / #cabdbf**. This mismatch occurs for every preset color I try. When I pick a custom color in Google Calendar this custom value *is* passed correctly via the API.

How do I get the correct color values for preset calendar colors via the Google Calendar API?

*Edit - Added code snippet below*

Extending class *Client*:

```
function getCalendars()
{
    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($this);
    $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();
    while (true) {
        foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {
            $calendars[] = $calendarListEntry;
        }
        $pageToken = $calendarList->getNextPageToken();
        if ($pageToken) {
            $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
            $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList($optParams);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $calendars;
}
```

```
function getColors()
{
    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($this);
    $colors = $service->colors->get();
    $col = [];
    foreach ($colors->getCalendar() as $key => $color) {
        $col['calendar'][$key] = $color;
    }
    foreach ($colors->getEvent() as $key => $color) {
        $col['event'][$key] = $color;
    }
    return $col;
}
```

Result of getCalendars:

```
[
    {
        ...
        "backgroundColor": "#16a765",
        "colorId": "8",
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
        "backgroundColor": "#cabdbf",  <-- Agenda color in example
        "colorId": "20",  <-- Agenda color ID in example
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
        "backgroundColor": "#9fc6e7",
        "colorId": "15",
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
        "backgroundColor": "#ffad46",
        "colorId": "6",
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
        "backgroundColor": "#ac725e",
        "colorId": "1",
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
        "backgroundColor": "#fbe983",
        "colorId": "11",
        ...
    }
]
```

Result of getColors:

```
{
    "calendar": {
        "1": {
            "background": "#ac725e",
            "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
        },
        ...
        "6": {
            "background": "#ffad46",
            "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
        },
        ...
        "8": {
            "background": "#16a765",
            "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
        },
        ...
        "11": {
            "background": "#fbe983",
            "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
        },
        ...
        "15": {
            "background": "#9fc6e7",
            "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
        },
        ...
        "20": {  <-- Agenda color ID in example
            "background": "#cabdbf", <-- Agenda color in example
            "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
        },
        ...
    },
    "event": {
        "1": {
            "background": "#a4bdfc",
            "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
        },
        ...
        "11": {
            "background": "#dc2127",
            "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Color **rgb(121, 85, 72) / #795548** is *not* part of the complete array returned by Google.

Actual Google Calendar source inspect:

[image: Google Calendar HTML element inspection]

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet you use to retrieve the colour?

Comment: Added code snippet & returned data object in original post

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

For anybody still wondering, the API always returns "classic" colors. The colors OP sees (and most probably you too) in UI are "modern". You can change between "classic" and "modern" in UI, but you can't (AFAIC) retrieve "modern" colors with API. I know, "WTF" indeed.

You can see the color comparisons in [Google Calendar Simple API's docs](https://google-calendar-simple-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/colors.html).